# Excel VBA: How to incorporate a variable loop number with a variable to use later in the code?

Tags: excel

I'm sorry in advance for sounding so dumb but here's what I'm trying to achieve.
I have 3 variables all named Rg1 Rg2 Rg3. No big deal. Easy peasy.
What I would like to do is look at range A1 through A3 and if the cell is blank, then set the associated range as nothing which will be omitted later.
It works great if I manually change the Rg# to nothing as in Rg2=Nothing

What I'm ultimately trying to do is set the rg# to either an actual value or Nothing. I'm just drawing a dead blank and can't figure out (or find an answer because of how I'm asking it I guess) how to do this.

So what I have is:

```vb
'define the ranges
rg1 = Range("B1")
rg2 = Range("B10")
rg3 = Range("C3")
'set the variable
For x = 1 To 3
    If Range("A" & x) <> "" Then
        Set rg(x) = rg(x)
    Else
        Set rg(x) = Nothing
    End If
```

The failure is the `rg(x)` and that is what I am asking for help with. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to learn how to use arrays.  I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()
    
    'Initialize an empty array variable as a range
    Dim rg(1 To 3) As Range
    
    'Populate the array with desired range objects
    Set rg(1) = Range("B1")
    Set rg(2) = Range("B10")
    Set rg(3) = Range("C3")
    
    'Perform loop
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To 3
        'Reference your array using the loop variable
        If Range("A" & x) <> "" Then
            rg(x).Value = Range("A" & x).Value
        Else
            Set rg(x) = Nothing
        End If
    Next x
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is definitely closer than where I was, but not exactly. I don't need the value of the range, I need to actually set the range from the predefined list that is later used in the union argument. Perhaps I should have included that and apologies for not mentioning.